Azure Windows Machine Vm Machine Not access in Local Machine to Powershell Script
I have run below code in my local machine access from Azure VM machine run Powershell script Get Date
Error show not access

Error occurred: Connecting to remote server 57.151.88.183 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles lim
its access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

I have get Date From Azure VM Machine in local system

Try using PING (Test-Connection) and see if you have a route to the machine.  Not sure if you having a routing issue or a connection issue (like port being blocked or TLS failing).

there is no "below code"
